# Reading notification for new meta post does not clear it

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications, moderator-tools

When I get a notification for a new meta post in the moderator inbox, it does appear in the notifications of the app. But I when I read it there, that does not clear the notification in the desktop version, so when I login to SE with a browser the inbox is still blue and the meta post unread.

This is on Android 5.0.1 (on a Nexus 9) and app version 1.0.60 if it matters.