# Mobile meta post notifications are no longer working

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, mobile-app

Us mods used to get mobile push notifications for new meta posts, but a while ago (I don't know exactly when), they stopped coming. Can they be turned back on?

I don't know if this is specific just to Gaming/Android.

Comment: Definitely not specific to gaming. I stopped getting PPCG and Puzzling meat post notifications a while back too.

Comment: What app? iOS or android?

Comment: I know I'm not getting them on Android.

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting Coffee ones either, so it's probably site-wide.

Comment: @Doorknob you mean the SE mobile app, or desktop notifications of some kind? The official app also doesn't show notifications like bounty expires or new badges etc. (which is by design, they simply never added them)

Comment: I don't remember ever getting them, but maybe I'm just misremembering.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The mobile app used to be linked to the mod inbox (which contains new meta post notifications). A while ago, that stopped working, and I don't get "new meta post" notifications on mobile anymore.

Comment: @Doorknob but you do get other mod messages?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think we used to, but definitely not anymore.

Comment: So the bug report should be "no more mod messages in mobile app", no? /cc @Doorknob.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We get other mod messages so infrequently on Arqade it's hard to know.

Comment: Well, maybe ask a SO mod who also using the app over at TL then? (or I can find something to custom-flag on Arqade ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Flags don't go to the mod inbox.

Comment: @Doorknob Not those, the other things that make the diamond go blue: e.g. mod messages

Comment: @Doorknob oh, this might explain the long time it's taking for custom flags to be handed then. Anyway, better find the scope of this bug, to help the team fix it faster. :)

Comment: There's been a lot of churn cleaning up the inbox.  I'm guessing that the mod inbox was never supposed to receive notification because the mod inbox doesn't appear in the app.  When you got a notification, was the flow basically to open the app, see the inbox with no new information, and just manually navigate to the site? (Basically http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254483/reading-notification-for-new-meta-post-does-not-clear-it)

Comment: @BrianNickel no, we just used to go straight to the meta question. Bear in mind, this stopped working a LOOOOOONG time ago. See [this arqade-mods-only transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30?m=13243505#13243505) on January 17th, 2014, where I expected a private message to give me  a notification.

Comment: (yes that is almost 26 months ago for those playing from home)

Comment: @badp It must have worked more recently than that, as I definitely remember it happening, and I wasn't a mod back then...

Comment: I don't receive any mod-menu notifications via the Android app -- new meta questions, or CM pings.  I *think* I used to get notifications for the first two (CM pings are newer).